# how to install windows xp from the second hard drive on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, hard-drive, windows-xp

i have ubuntu 13.04 on the first HDD but can not recognize the second HDD with Windows XP after reboot of PC in order to nest OS es together, what should i do further?

Comment: Seems like you may need to provide some additional detail on this.  It sounds like we need clarification on how you're booting.  Are you using GRUB?  Did you reconfigure GRUB to recognize the second HDD as having its own bootloader?  Or instead, are you strictly going by boot-device order from the BIOS?  Did the second HDD already have Windows XP installed on it prior to physically connecting it to your system?  A little more detail would probably benefit us in helping you.  ;)

Comment: go by BIOS order, Windows XP installed prior to physical connection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Windows 10 after Ubuntu on a second drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808788/installing-windows-10-after-ubuntu-on-a-second-drive)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going entirely by BIOS order, you need to do one of two things:

1. Have GRUB recognize the secondary HDD's boot sector (Windows) and be able to launch off of the 2nd drive on its own.  Run `boot-repair` while in Ubuntu, and have it Scan your available HDDs/systems (will do this automatically usually), or if you're aware of how to configure GRUB on your own, set it up manually yourself.
2. Alternatively, you could do the painful method and assign the boot order in the BIOS manually every single time you want to switch systems... but that seems painful and unnecessary if you can simply use GRUB the whole time.

If you have any questions or issues regarding configuring GRUB to boot off of the second disk, I'd recommend you visit [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2072950) for some basic rundowns of how to do this.  It's not exactly the situation you may be having, but may give a better idea of how to accomplish a similar situation.  Feel free to post follow-ups if you have issues.