# Installing Windows 10 after Ubuntu on a second drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed and running fine. It boots from an SSD and has a larger HD for storage.

I would like to install Windows 10 for gaming and have bought an SSD specifically for Windows.

Normally you would go the other way around, Windows first and then Ubuntu, but I don't really want to reinstall Ubuntu.

Is disconnecting the two "Linux" hard drives and only connecting the new SSD for Windows, while installing Windows the way to go? Afterwards I would connect all three HDs and set the Ubuntu SSD as the boot drive.

I don't mind having to go into the BIOS when I need to boot in Windows, if necessary.

**TLDR:** Ubuntu installed on SSD, want Windows 10 installed on second SSD. Disconnect Ubuntu SSD, install Windows 10, reconnect Ubuntu SSD, boot from desired SSD. Feasible?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about SSD because search for "installing windows after ubuntu"  finds lots of duplicates, including this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/129058/how-to-install-windows-7-after-ubuntu-and-dual-boot? In that case perhaps make your title more precise.

Comment: I'm asking specifically if installing Windows on its own SSD alongside an SSD with Ubuntu. The duplicates mostly concerns single-drive dual-boot instalations. EDIT: I've clarified the question in the title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I went ahead and did it. The operation was successful.

I:

1. Disconnected the Linux HDs
2. Connected the new SSD
3. Installed Windows on the new SSD
4. Reconnected the Linux HDs
5. Set the Linux SSD as default boot-drive
6. Booted into Ubuntu
7. Mounted the Windows partition in Nautilus
8. Ran `sudo update-grub`

Grub now presents me with a list on startup were I can choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

The only small problem I had was in step 7. For some reason Ubuntu claimed that Windows had not shut down properly and thus could't mount the disk. A  quick reboot into Windows and then back into Ubuntu solved it, and the drive mounted fine.

I'm not sure if disconnecting the Linux HDs were actually necessary. I did it to be extra sure I wouldn't accidentally mess up the Ubuntu installation. The Windows and Ubuntu installs are on identical SSDs.

Comment: You mean "between Ubuntu and Windows", not Ubuntu and Linux :)

Comment: this worked for me :)

Comment: Worked for me as well. Had same issue on step 7 and instead of restarting I mounted the EFI partition using the Disk utility